# office web apps server 2013 - Got an server error when open /op/generate.aspx

Tags: ms-office, ms-wopi

I set up an office web apps server 2013 in windows server 2012 R2, it is good to open this link `http://localhost/hosting/discovery`, means the office web apss server 2013 is running well.

But when I tried to open this link `http://localhost/op/generate.aspx`, it gives an error : `A big red X`, server error sorry for the mistake. We have recorded an error for the server administrator.

[image]

I was looking for some blogs, somesay that is causing by logging in the website with the system account, but I dont know what is the system account, and is that logging means the iis service?

I am not use WOPI and sharepoint, what I want is only use office web apps server 2013 to provide view & edit doc and docx files in browser.

Please help, thanks!

PS. If the question not meet the requirement, comment it, I will edit it.

eidt 1 :

I had solve this problem, I had installed AD and OWA in one server.

Install them in different server will ok.

But there is another problem :

When open a word file, It gave an alert:

Microsoft Word Web App

sorry, some problem had appeared, cant open this file.

How to fix this ...

update :

I finally solved it by changing another server to install OWA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to open documents from [UNC paths](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_web_apps_server_2013_support_blog/2013/12/27/how-to-test-viewing-office-documents-using-the-office-web-apps-2013-viewer/) then run the following command in the PowerShell on your OOS/OWA machine.

```
Set-OfficeWebAppsFarm -OpenFromURLEnabled
```

If you need to connect your OOS/OWA to a WOPI host (SharePoint or a [custom host](https://github.com/petrsvihlik/WopiHost)) then http://localhost/hosting/discovery is a good enough indication that the instance works fine.

Comment: Thanks for help, but it is not the reason. I dont know why,  but I change a server to install OWA, it worked.

Comment: And with WOPI, docx files can be edit in browser. It is good.

Comment: But it cannot support doc files, is SharePoint support it ?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you are asking whether the OWA or OOS support the old proprietary "doc" format. I don't think so. 
Regarding Sharepoint, I'm not sure what you are asking about. You can definitely upload *.doc files there but editing won't be possible because Sharepoint uses OWA/OOS to do view and edit documents.

Comment: OK, I get it, you mean that OWA does not support edit `*.doc` files, it doesn't matter use with WOPI or Sharepoint.

Comment: Yes, [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2028380/unable-to-view-or-edit-office-files-by-using-office-online-or-office-web-apps) is a list of supported file types. Basically, if you want to support editing you have to use the new Office Open XML formats (docx, pptx, xlsx). But viewing of "doc" should be supported as well. On the other hand, viewing of "xls" is not supported.